# View size of CPU cache through the command-line?

Tags: command-line, cpu, cache, system-info, cpuinfo

How do I view the size of my CPU cache using the command-line?

I want to view information on L1, L2 and L3 cache.

Also, would it be possible to ouput *only* information on cache, so that all other information is filtered out?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`lscpu` will provide the info you're looking for.

`lscpu | grep "cache"` to filter out only cache info. This will result in something like:

```
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              3072K
```

Answer (score 5):

**sysfs**

```
for d in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cache/index*;
  do tail -c+1 $d/{level,type,size}
  echo
done
```

Gives:

```
==> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cache/index0/level <==
1

==> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cache/index0/type <==
Data

==> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cache/index0/size <==
32K

==> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cache/index1/level <==
1

==> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cache/index1/type <==
Instruction

==> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cache/index1/size <==
32K

==> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cache/index2/level <==
2

==> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cache/index2/type <==
Unified

==> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cache/index2/size <==
256K

==> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cache/index3/level <==
3

==> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cache/index3/type <==
Unified

==> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cache/index3/size <==
8192K
```

**`getconf`**

```
getconf -a | grep CACHE
```

gives:

```
LEVEL1_ICACHE_SIZE                 32768
LEVEL1_ICACHE_ASSOC                8
LEVEL1_ICACHE_LINESIZE             64
LEVEL1_DCACHE_SIZE                 32768
LEVEL1_DCACHE_ASSOC                8
LEVEL1_DCACHE_LINESIZE             64
LEVEL2_CACHE_SIZE                  262144
LEVEL2_CACHE_ASSOC                 8
LEVEL2_CACHE_LINESIZE              64
LEVEL3_CACHE_SIZE                  20971520
LEVEL3_CACHE_ASSOC                 20
LEVEL3_CACHE_LINESIZE              64
LEVEL4_CACHE_SIZE                  0
LEVEL4_CACHE_ASSOC                 0
LEVEL4_CACHE_LINESIZE              0
```

Or for a single level:

```
getconf LEVEL2_CACHE_SIZE
```

The cool thing about this interface is that it is just a wrapper around the POSIX `sysconf` C function (cache arguments are non-POSIX extensions), and so it can be used from C code as well:

```
long l2 = sysconf(_SC_LEVEL2_CACHE_SIZE);
```

Tested in Ubuntu 16.04.

**x86 CPUID instruction**

The CPUID x86 instruction also offers cache information, and can be directly accessed by userland: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID

glibc seems to use that method for x86. I haven't confirmed by step debugging / instruction tracing, but the source for 2.28 [`sysdeps/x86/cacheinfo.c`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/x86/cacheinfo.c;h=b9444ddd52051e05183463340f4dd3cf3e61f4dc;hb=3c03baca37fdcb52c3881e653ca392bba7a99c2b#l281) does that:

```
__cpuid (2, eax, ebx, ecx, edx);
```

TODO create a minimal C example, lazy now, asked at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14283171/how-to-receive-l1-l2-l3-cache-size-using-cpuid-instruction-in-x86

ARM also has an architecture-defined mechanism to find cache sizes through registers such as the Cache Size ID Register (CCSIDR), see the [ARMv8 Programmers' Manual](https://static.docs.arm.com/den0024/a/DEN0024A_v8_architecture_PG.pdf) 11.6 "Cache discovery" for an overview.